# Struggling to automate terraform WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cidr

I'm trying to terraform WAF ACL and associated rules. The terraform stack I'm working on is identical in DEV, QA , and PROD, differences are all handled using different variables. So my idea is to store a list of CIDRs in a variable, and automatically create ALLOW rules for each. My limited knowledge is slowing me down though. It creates the ipsets perfectly, but the rules and ACL complain,

```
variable cloud_allowed_cidr_list = {type="list" default=["1.2.3.4/32","4.3.2.1/32"]}

resource "aws_waf_ipset" "ipset" {
  count = "${length(var.cloud_allowed_cidr_list)}"
  name = "ipset-${count.index}"

  ip_set_descriptors {
    type  = "IPV4"
    value = "${element(var.cloud_allowed_cidr_list, count.index)}"
  }
}


resource "aws_waf_rule" "matchIPrule" {
  count = "${length(var.cloud_allowed_cidr_list)}"
  depends_on  = ["aws_waf_ipset.ipset"]
  name        = "matchMancIPrule${count.index}"
  metric_name = "matchMancIPrule${count.index}"

  predicates {
    data_id = "${aws_waf_ipset.ipset.*.id}"
    negated = false
    type    = "IPMatch"
  }
}


resource "aws_waf_web_acl" "waf_acl" {
  depends_on  = ["aws_waf_ipset.ipset", "aws_waf_rule.matchIPrule"]
  name        = "mancACL${count.index}"
  metric_name = "mancACL${count.index}"

  default_action {
    type = "BLOCK"
  }

  rules {
    action {
      type = "ALLOW"
    }

    priority = "${count.index}"
    rule_id  = "${aws_waf_rule.matchIPrule.id}"
    type     = "REGULAR"
  }
}
```

It fell apart when I realised that rules have multiple predicates, and the ACL has multiple rules .....how do you create that dynamically ? If anyone has any examples of doing something similar I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Do you have different amounts of IP ranges for each of dev/qa/prod? The fact that the rules/predicates are using a sub resource instead of a fully fledged attachment resource like `aws_ebs_volume_attachment` makes this tricky but if you actually have a requirement that you want to only whitelist traffic for dev/qa from one set of IPs and allow all for production then this is easier. It's hard to know what to suggest without a wider picture of what you're trying to achieve though.

Comment: Yes , different ip ranges for each environment, so dev can be our office LAN, QA can be our office plus some selected third parties, PROD can be the whole world.

Answer (score 0):

Since the release of 0.12 you can now do this using dynamic blocks.

No need to use count to iterate over your array.

```
resource "aws_waf_ipset" "ipset" {
  name = "youripset"

  dynamic "ip_set_descriptors" {
    iterator = ip
    for_each = var.cloud_allowed_cidr_list

    content {
      type  = "IPV4"
      value = ip.value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm attempting to use this method currently. However it seems to always result in a meaningless diff due to randomly reordering ip_set_descriptors blocks.

Comment: my comment above was a bit premature. I discovered that the AWS provider cannot realize the equivalence of abbreviated IPv6 addresses and the full form. Once I expanded the addresses to the full form and ensured they were a sorted set, my problem was solved.